# What does it mean that sea turtles get a smaller ''salary premium''?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

For starters a bit of background about [sea turtles](http://books.google.nl/books?id=Bj6X_D40c0EC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=sea+turtle+china+phenomena&source=bl&ots=31eo9Y8hhR&sig=U1mrz5PCaRCrvgiJGjZxaxXcCzY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EDFrU7_6OsP-PKXRgPgF&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sea%20turtle%20china%20phenomena&f=false) to give some context to the question:

> The terms "sea turtle" (a pun on "hai gui") and "seaweed" (a pun on "hai dai") are homonyms for "return from abroad" and "return and wait for work" in Chinese respectively.

---

My question does not refer to the sea turtles, but to the expression **salary premium** in the following sentence:

> Several studies show that sea turtles on average must now wait longer to find a less senior post at a smaller *salary premium* over local hires.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning some more context. I _may_ be the only one that was not aware of this meaning of sea turtles, but I doubt it :)

Comment: @oerkelens  the same world that auto-corrects your name to weekend perhaps?

Comment: @Frank: no, actually, the expression means something, as I just found out.

Comment: @oerkelens May I enquire what it means? Just seen your answer, never heard that before.

Comment: I added a reference to my answer :) I never heard it before either.

Comment: Thanks to @oerkelens' due-diligence, we now have a definition of 'sea turtles' (and I can gratefully say I've already learnt something today), but it really would have been useful to have included it in the question itself!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the sea turtles reference to the question, to avoid future confusion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A premium is something that is paid extra. In this sentence, the implication is that sea turtles (people returning to China, as far as I understand), used to get a higher salary than local people that had never left the country - for the same job.

What the sentence say is that now, the difference in salary between the locals and the sea turtles is getting smaller, the sea turtles do not find employment as quickly as they used to, and they are forced to accept less senior positions.

As an extra for those puzzled like me by the [sea turtle](http://books.google.nl/books?id=Bj6X_D40c0EC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=sea+turtle+china+phenomena&source=bl&ots=31eo9Y8hhR&sig=U1mrz5PCaRCrvgiJGjZxaxXcCzY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EDFrU7_6OsP-PKXRgPgF&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sea%20turtle%20china%20phenomena&f=false) reference:

> The terms "sea turtle" (a pun on "hai gui") and "seaweed" (a pun on "hai dai") are homonyms for "return from abroad" and "return and wait for work" in Chinese respectively.

Comment: very useful! And sea turtles are people who return to China. Because in Mandarin, the phrase "return across the sea" sounds similar to that animal's name- hai gui ( the same animals as sea turtles).

Comment: Thanks -- you've tortoise all something we didn't know before.

Comment: Do they all have nest eggs?

Comment: @Edwin -- They're always hatching something.

Comment: But sea turtles must be worth their salt.